# App link in Nook AppStore

Tags: android, nook, nook-tablet

I am developing application that support Nook Kindle. I have to specify my nook app link to Rate my app. For Kindle I Used "http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=pacakgeName" and for google play the link is "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pacakgeName".

Similarly is there and link to find my application by just giving the package name etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't show "Rate my app" dialog, such dialogs are so annoying...:(

Comment: @shoerat Thanks for suggestion. This is not for rate my app. This to provide app link to the users through website. If you have any solution pls provide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nook App store uses `EAN` to build the `URL`, not package name. `EAN` stands for Internation Article Number (renamed from European Article Number but the old abbreviation remains).

Template:

```
https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/tools/dev/linkManager/{EAN}
```

For example:

```
https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/tools/dev/linkManager/2940043865557
```

links to The Smithsonian Channel app with EAN 2940043865557.

More info:

[Nook Developer Forum](https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/20741752-Link-to-App-In-Store-) - Nook Dev Relations confirms we should use EAN to link, but URL examples don't work.

[Corona Labs Forum](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/28220-app-url-before-launch-kindle-nook/) - Correct URL example.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferrable to use deep store linking as described here:
[Nook deep linking](http://onnook.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/nook-api-shop-details-com-bn-sdk-shop-details/)

Code snippet from the link above:

```
import android.content.Intent;
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction( "com.bn.sdk.shop.details" );
i.putExtra( "product_details_ean" , "2940043350251" );
startActivity( i );
```